# Actual Vs Plan in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am having a problem in PowerBi, where I want to get results for Actual vs Plan. I have 3 tables , Book Sales Table, Plan table and Titles table. I would like the result as in Desired Output table.

[Book Sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPxBC.png)

[Titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFzld.png)

[Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYvso.png)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at8sO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Power Query M Code

- Join the Sales and Titles tables to extract the publishing unit for each book type
- Add a column representing the start of each month for each sales number
- Group by BOM and Unit and aggregage with Sum in case you have multiple sales/unit in a month
- Join this last table with the Plan table based on Unit and Date

***M Code***

```
let

//Join the Sales and Titles to get the Publishing units
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(#"Book Sales", {"Book ID"}, Titles, {"Book Id"}, "Titles", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Titles" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Titles", {"Publishing Unit"}, {"Publishing Unit"}),

//add start of month column to merge with Plan
    bom  = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Titles", "BOM", each Date.StartOfMonth([Invoice Date]),type date),

//Group by unit and bom columns in case you happen to have multiple sales in the same month
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(bom, {"Publishing Unit", "BOM"}, {{"Sales amount", each List.Sum([Sales amount]), type number}}),

//Join with Plan using bom and date as the key
    salesVplan = Table.NestedJoin(Plan,{"Business Unit","Date"}, #"Grouped Rows", {"Publishing Unit","BOM"},"joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(salesVplan, "joined", {"Sales amount"}, {"Sales amount"})
in
    #"Expanded joined"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in several different ways, but I would recommend doing this in SQL personally. This means that you can:
Select from all the tables you want to show, into the same table. Lets call it Products.
Then you join in the values that you want on that.

This way, there is no dax calculation that takes time, but rather just something that takes time while you refresh the dataset itself.